# How to import from this library, NetBeans, Java

Tags: java, netbeans, import, netbeans-8

I'm trying to import the BigDecimalMath class into my current project. I created a new library by going to Tools -> Libraries -> New Library. I called the library BigDecimalMath, as you can see below. I added a new JAR/Folder and then selected the download from Cornell's website, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3030v2). [Direct download](http://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v2).

[image: Library screenshot]

I'm unsure of how to import it into my class now. This library is part of my current project. I've tried `import org.nevec.rjm` and some other things, but I think I'm doing something wrong. Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a source version of that library. Your window displays a jar containing `org.nevec.rjm.BigDecimalMath.java`. I think you need to download a binary version of the jar and add that to your class-path. Then you would import that one class with,

```
import org.nevec.rjm.BigDecimalMath;
```

or the entire package with,

```
import org.nevec.rjm.*;
```

Alternatively, you might be able to build the library from your src jar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure if there is a binary version available on Cornell's website. Can you please explain how to build the library or point me toward a guideline that might show me how? I'm quite new to programming.